# Emacs Lisp unique window name for split identification and deletion

Tags: emacs, lisp

I am trying to uniquely identify a window,
so that I can select and delete the window if I press a key over again, though I am having trouble doing this.

```
(setq split-window-right-toggle-var nil)

(defun split-window-right-toggle ()
  (interactive)
  (if split-window-right-toggle-var 
      (progn
        (right-split-undo)
        (setq split-window-right-toggle-var nil))
    (progn
      (right-split-do)
      (setq split-window-right-toggle-var t))))

(defun right-split-do ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-right)
  (other-window 1))

(defun right-split-undo ()
  (interactive)
  (other-window -1)
  (delete-window))
```

The issue with this code is that it heavily depends on which window is active, there for can
change the state of my windows and delete the wrong window, can I uniquely give my window a name then target that window name for deletion ? I am really new at Emacs lisp and would appreciate any help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`(selected-window)` returns a reference to the current window.

`(next-window)` returns the next window.  Use Emacs' self documenting features
to find out more or refer to the manual.

### Here is how I would write your command

```
(defvar ej-spit-window-saved nil)

(defun ej-split-window-right-toggle ()
  "toggle split right"
  (interactive)
  (setq ej-split-window-saved
        (if (and ej-split-window-saved
                 (frame-visible-p (window-frame ej-split-window-saved)))
            (delete-window ej-split-window-saved)
          (split-window-right))))
```

### Notes

- prefix functions/variables for easier debugging.
- it's never too early to document code.

Comment: I think what the asker wants is to select windows regardless of which window is selected. These functions are still window dependent.

Comment: He wants to uniquely identify a window with a name, _not_ manually name a window.  I'm pointing out a name isn't necessary as the "window" object itself is readily accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out something like this:

```
(setq window-names (make-hash-table :test 'equal ))                                                                                                  

(defun name-window ()                                                                                                                                
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                      
  (let ((name (read-input "Name: ")))                                                                                                                
    (setf (gethash name window-names) (selected-window))))                                                                                           

(defun del-window ()                                                                                                                                 
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                      
  (let ((name (read-input "Name: ")))                                                                                                                
    (delete-window (gethash name window-names))))
```